# Override PartnerAPI ClassLoader

Tags: marketing-cloud, integration, class, java, fuel-sdk

We have exported as `Runnable JAR` (Extract required libriries into generated JAR `option`) our proyect (which has dependecies the fuelsdk and axis).

So, there are some classes which read properties from resource path.

Example:

ETConfiguration

```
file = "/fuelsdk.properties";
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream(file);
if (is == null) {
       throw new ETSdkException("error opening " + file);
}
```

PartnerAPI

```
public class PartnerAPI extends Service {

    public final static URL WSDL_LOCATION;

    public final static QName SERVICE = new QName("http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI", "PartnerAPI");
    public final static QName Soap = new QName("http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI", "Soap");
    static {
        URL url = PartnerAPI.class.getClassLoader().getResource("/etframework.wsdl");
        if (url == null) {
            url = PartnerAPI.class.getClassLoader().getResource("etframework.wsdl");
        }
        if (url == null) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(PartnerAPI.class.getName())
                .log(java.util.logging.Level.INFO, 
                     "Can not initialize the default wsdl from {0}", "classpath:/etframework.wsdl");
        }       
        WSDL_LOCATION = url;   
    }
...
}
```

We have found how to override Classloader for ETConfiguration by adding these sentenses:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = ETConfiguration.class.getClassLoader();
Class aClass = classLoader.loadClass("com.foo.bar");
```

but, this solution is not working for `PartnerAPI`.

What can we do?

**UPDATED**

This issue is solved by creating `src/main/resources` folder and inserting all property files. `ClassLoader` is not necessary any more.

But now, we are getting soap service error (probably Fuel SDK bug) when calling

`ETClient client = new ETClient();`

Here is the error code:

```
2014-06-23T16:17:55.509+0200 main com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETRestConnection DEBUG: GET https://www.exacttargetapis.com/platform/v1/endpoints/soap 
2014-06-23T16:17:55.740+0200 main com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETClient DEBUG: requesting new access token... 
2014-06-23T16:17:55.761+0200 main com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETRestConnection DEBUG: POST https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken 
2014-06-23T16:17:55.762+0200 main com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETRestConnection DEBUG: Content-Type: application/json 
2014-06-23T16:17:55.770+0200 main com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETRestConnection DEBUG: { 
2014-06-23T16:17:55.770+0200 main com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETRestConnection DEBUG:   "clientId": "XXX", 
2014-06-23T16:17:55.771+0200 main com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETRestConnection DEBUG:   "clientSecret": "YYY", 
2014-06-23T16:17:55.771+0200 main com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETRestConnection DEBUG:   "accessType": "offline" 
2014-06-23T16:17:55.771+0200 main com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETRestConnection DEBUG: } 
2014-06-23T16:17:59.214+0200 main com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETRestConnection DEBUG: 200 OK 
2014-06-23T16:17:59.218+0200 main com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETRestConnection DEBUG: { 
2014-06-23T16:17:59.218+0200 main com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETRestConnection DEBUG:   "accessToken": "ZZZ", 
2014-06-23T16:17:59.219+0200 main com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETRestConnection DEBUG:   "expiresIn": 3554, 
2014-06-23T16:17:59.219+0200 main com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETRestConnection DEBUG:   "refreshToken": "ZZZZ" 
2014-06-23T16:17:59.220+0200 main com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETRestConnection DEBUG: } 
2014-06-23T16:17:59.221+0200 main com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETClient DEBUG: received token: 
2014-06-23T16:17:59.225+0200 main com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETClient DEBUG:   accessToken: ZZZ
2014-06-23T16:17:59.225+0200 main com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETClient DEBUG:   expiresIn: 3554 
2014-06-23T16:17:59.226+0200 main com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETClient DEBUG:   refreshToken: ZZZZ
2014-06-23T16:17:59.234+0200 main com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETClient DEBUG: new access token expires at Mon Jun 23 17:17:13 CEST 2014 
2014-06-23T16:17:59.234+0200 main com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETRestConnection DEBUG: Accept: application/json 
2014-06-23T16:18:00.150+0200 main com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETRestConnection DEBUG: 200 OK 
2014-06-23T16:18:00.152+0200 main com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETRestConnection DEBUG: { 
2014-06-23T16:18:00.152+0200 main com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETRestConnection DEBUG:   "type": "soap", 
2014-06-23T16:18:00.153+0200 main com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETRestConnection DEBUG:   "url": "https://webservice.s4.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx" 
2014-06-23T16:18:00.153+0200 main com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETRestConnection DEBUG: } 
2014-06-23T16:18:00.154+0200 main com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETClient DEBUG: SOAP endpoint: https://webservice.s4.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx 
23-jun-2014 16:18:04 org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean buildServiceFromWSDL
INFO: Creating Service {http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI}PartnerAPI from WSDL: file:/C:/workspace/prueba/bin/etframework.wsdl
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.getPort(ServiceImpl.java:334)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.getPort(ServiceImpl.java:319)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:92)
    at com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.internal.PartnerAPI.getSoap(PartnerAPI.java:60)
    at com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETSoapConnection.<init>(ETSoapConnection.java:74)
    at com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETClient.<init>(ETClient.java:134)
    at com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETClient.<init>(ETClient.java:69)
    at Probando.main(Probando.java:33)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientFactoryBean.create(ClientFactoryBean.java:97)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxyFactoryBean.create(ClientProxyFactoryBean.java:156)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.create(JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.java:156)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.createPort(ServiceImpl.java:465)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.getPort(ServiceImpl.java:332)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.BusException: No binding factory for namespace http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/ registered.
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.managers.BindingFactoryManagerImpl.getBindingFactory(BindingFactoryManagerImpl.java:123)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:116)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientFactoryBean.create(ClientFactoryBean.java:90)
    ... 11 more
```

Normally, it should print this message:

```
2014-06-23T16:31:45.157+0200 main com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETRestConnection DEBUG: GET https://www.exacttargetapis.com/platform/v1/endpoints/soap 
2014-06-23T16:31:45.413+0200 main com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETClient DEBUG: requesting new access token... 
2014-06-23T16:31:45.442+0200 main com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETRestConnection DEBUG: POST https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken 
2014-06-23T16:31:45.443+0200 main com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETRestConnection DEBUG: Content-Type: application/json 
2014-06-23T16:31:45.449+0200 main com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETRestConnection DEBUG: { 
2014-06-23T16:31:45.450+0200 main com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETRestConnection DEBUG:   "clientId": "XXX", 
2014-06-23T16:31:45.451+0200 main com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETRestConnection DEBUG:   "clientSecret": "YYY", 
2014-06-23T16:31:45.451+0200 main com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETRestConnection DEBUG:   "accessType": "offline" 
2014-06-23T16:31:45.452+0200 main com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETRestConnection DEBUG: } 
2014-06-23T16:31:48.972+0200 main com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETRestConnection DEBUG: 200 OK 
2014-06-23T16:31:48.977+0200 main com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETRestConnection DEBUG: { 
2014-06-23T16:31:48.977+0200 main com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETRestConnection DEBUG:   "accessToken": "ZZZ", 
2014-06-23T16:31:48.978+0200 main com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETRestConnection DEBUG:   "expiresIn": 3600, 
2014-06-23T16:31:48.978+0200 main com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETRestConnection DEBUG:   "refreshToken": "ZZZZ" 
2014-06-23T16:31:48.979+0200 main com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETRestConnection DEBUG: } 
2014-06-23T16:31:48.980+0200 main com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETClient DEBUG: received token: 
2014-06-23T16:31:49.013+0200 main com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETClient DEBUG:   accessToken: ZZZ
2014-06-23T16:31:49.013+0200 main com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETClient DEBUG:   expiresIn: 3600 
2014-06-23T16:31:49.013+0200 main com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETClient DEBUG:   refreshToken: ZZZZ
2014-06-23T16:31:49.019+0200 main com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETClient DEBUG: new access token expires at Mon Jun 23 17:31:49 CEST 2014 
2014-06-23T16:31:49.019+0200 main com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETRestConnection DEBUG: Accept: application/json 
2014-06-23T16:31:49.990+0200 main com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETRestConnection DEBUG: 200 OK 
2014-06-23T16:31:49.992+0200 main com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETRestConnection DEBUG: { 
2014-06-23T16:31:49.992+0200 main com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETRestConnection DEBUG:   "type": "soap", 
2014-06-23T16:31:49.992+0200 main com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETRestConnection DEBUG:   "url": "https://webservice.s4.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx" 
2014-06-23T16:31:49.993+0200 main com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETRestConnection DEBUG: } 
2014-06-23T16:31:49.994+0200 main com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETClient DEBUG: SOAP endpoint: https://webservice.s4.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx 
23-jun-2014 16:31:56 org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean buildServiceFromWSDL
INFO: Creating Service {http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI}PartnerAPI from WSDL: file:/C:/workspace/fuelsdk/target/classes/etframework.wsdl
2014-06-23T16:32:00.785+0200 main com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETSoapConnection DEBUG: updated SOAP header with new access token ZZZ
```

Comment: How did you resolve your problems?